# Loop Through All DataTable in DataSet Using A For Loop

Tags: c#, for-loop, foreach, datatable, dataset

Anyone know how can I loop through all datatable in Dataset with a `For Loop` instead of `foreach` loop?

I know foreach loop can do this but **I want to use a For loop instead.**

For example:

```
foreach (DataTable table in ds.Tables)
{

}
```

**I would like to use a For Loop instead.**

Appreciate if someone can help me on this

Comment: I wonder why a `DataTableCollection`(that's returned from `DataSet.Tables`) doesn't implement `IList` but only `ICollection` which has no random access but only a `Count` property. It's an [indexer property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cfsd7dz4(v=vs.110).aspx) which allows to accesss a table via index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DataSet  dt = new DataSet();
//Populate dataset here
//Iterate throuh datatables inside the dataset
for(int i=0;i<dt.Tables.Count;i++)
    {
      DataTable temptable = dt.Tables[i]; // this will give you the datatable in each iteration level
        //Do your doce here
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ds.Tables.Count` property to do this:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables.Count; i++)
 {
     // access your table with indexes:
     Console.WriteLine(ds.Tables[i].ToString());
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DataSet dsTemp = new DataSet();
for (int tableIndex = 0; tableIndex < dsTemp.Tables.Count; tableIndex++)
{
    DataTable dtIndex = dsTemp.Tables[tableIndex];
    //code here
}
```

By this way...